# ASP.Net MVC Models: MinLength Limit only in StringLength validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm going to create a property for my Model which got minLength = 6 but no limit for its maximum.

Using below syntax, Visual Studio says there are no overloads for below syntax  and I should put MaxmimumLength as first parameter. So are there any `MAX_LENGTH` constants or such thing to put as first parameter?

```
    [StringLength(MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[StringLength(Int32.MaxValue, MinimumLength = 6)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: Will `Int32.MaxValue`  map to `nvarchar(MAX)` when appled to code first migrations?